# Using picklist value in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, aura

I am creating multiple row with sobject type abc and Reason__c as picklist value. with the below code :

```
<aura:component controller="Controller" Implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">     
    <aura:attribute name="accountList" type="abc[]" access="global"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="abcRec" type="abc[]" access="global"/>


      <lightning:input name="strtdate" type="date" required="true" maxlength="50" label="Date From" value="{!acc.Start_Date__c}" />
   </td>
   <td>
      <lightning:input name="enddate" type="date"  maxlength="10" label="Date  To" value="{!acc.End_Date__c}" />
   </td>
   <td>
      <lightning:input name="Reason"   label="Reason" value="{!acc.Reason__c}"/>
   </td>

I am pushing the values from helper using the below code

accountList.push({
            'sobjectType': 'abc',
            'Start_Date__c': '',
            'End_Date__c': '',
            'Reason__c': '',
            'Comments__c': ''
        });
        component.set("v.accountList", accountList);
```

I need to make reason as picklist value without making the code complex. 
Tried to use  `value="{!acc.Reason__c}"` however its not working . Any workaround

Comment: what do you mean "its not working", is it empty,are you getting any error ?

Comment: picklist values are not coming , Want to render picklist values from the field

Comment: are you creating record of abc type and you are asking why you cant see picklist values that you can select in "Reason__c" or are you fetching the record  and just displaying them and you dont see the picklist value assign to that record

Comment: while creating records I want the reason which is a picklist field at backend should render its values for input name reason.

Comment: if you are just creating record you can also use lightning data service which is much easier https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Comment: if you dont want to use lds you have to call apex and get picklist values from there you wont automatically get them